# Android Test - function with queryIntentActivities return empty list

Tags: java, android, kotlin, user-interface, testing

so i'm working on a UI test class, the problem i'm facing is that the function triggered by my UI test contains a check with `queryIntentActivities()` and this function is returning me an empty list and i can't figure why. Any idea ?

The test class :

```kotlin
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TestMyActivity {

    private lateinit var scenario: ActivityScenario<MyActivity>


    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MyActivity::class.java)

    }

    @Test
    fun testMybutton() {
        scenario.onActivity {

            onView(withId(R.id.my_recyclerview))
                .perform(
                    RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem<ViewHolder>(
                        hasDescendant(withText("text that match")),
                        click()
                    )
                )


            intended(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL))
         }
     }
```

The function called on click :

```java
public static void startCall(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
        try {
            Uri phoneUri = Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(phoneUri);

            // Check if some app in device can handle this intent ( = check if
            // device
            // can use
            // dial feature, example : tablet can't)
            PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> infos = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
            if (infos.size() > 0) {
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you testing on Android 11 or higher? If so, did you add a `<queries>` element to your manifest, to satisfy package visibility rules?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yep i'm testing on Android 11 and i added the

```<queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        </intent>
 </queries>```

but it did not change anything. By the way the test file is under the test directory and not AndroidTest

Comment: Then I would not expect `queryIntentActivities()` to do much of anything. You are using some fake `Context` and fake `PackageManager` in a unit test, as it is not running on Android. I would move this to be an instrumented test, under `androidTest/`.

Comment: Aaaaah yes ok, i'll try that ! Thanks for your answer !